# not sure how to use XmlNode in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, xmlnode

In C# I need to use XmlNode to get values from these attributes as follows:

Root element (ServerConfig):

- type
- version
- createDate

Child nodes (Items):

- name
- source
- destination

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServerConfig type="ProjectName" version ="1.1.1.2" createDate ="2013-07-30T15:07:19.3859287+02:00" >
<items>
    <item  name="fs" type="directory" source="C:\temp\source" destination="C:\temp\target" action="Create" />
    <item  name="testdoc.txt" type="file" source="C:\temp\source" destination="C:\temp\target" action="Update" />
</items>
</ServerConfig>
```

C#:

```
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fileManager.ConfigFile);
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode node = doc.ReadNode(reader);

        // failed to get values here
        var Version = node.Attributes["version"].Value;
        var Type = node.Attributes["type"].Value;
        var Date = node.Attributes["createDate"].Value;

        //how to get values from items/item attributes here?
```

Your example code much appreciated thanks :)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [LINQ to XML](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx) (which is preferable in latest .Net versions)

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileManager.ConfigFile);
var serverConfig = xdoc.Root;
string version = (string)serverConfig.Attribute("version");
DateTime date = (DateTime)serverConfig.Attribute("createDate");
string type = (string)serverConfig.Attribute("type");

var items = from item in serverConfig.Element("items").Elements()
            select new {
                Name = (string)item.Attribute("name"),
                Type = (string)item.Attribute("type"),
                Source = (string)item.Attribute("source"),
                Destination = (string)item.Attribute("destination")
            };
```

Take a look - few lines of code and file parsed into strongly-typed variables. Even *date* is a `DateTime` object instead of string. And *items* are collection of anonymous objects with properties corresponding to xml attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You should use XPath to get items and loop on the result ;)

Something like this:

```
foreach (XmlNode item in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("items/item"))
{
  var Name = item.Attributes["name"].Value;
  var Source= item.Attributes["source"].Value;
  var Destination = item.Attributes["destination"].Value;
}
```

To get your root element you can use `doc.DocumentElement` ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx):

Classes:

```
public class ServerConfig
{
    public ServerConfig()
    {
        Items = new List<Item>();
    }

    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("createDate")]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("items")]
    [XmlArrayItem("item")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("source")]
    public string Source { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("destination")]
    public string Destination { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("action")]
    public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

Example:

```
var data = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
    <ServerConfig type=""ProjectName"" version =""1.1.1.2"" createDate =""2013-07-30T15:07:19.3859287+02:00"" >
    <items>
        <item  name=""fs"" type=""directory"" source=""C:\temp\source"" destination=""C:\temp\target"" action=""Create"" />
        <item  name=""testdoc.txt"" type=""file"" source=""C:\temp\source"" destination=""C:\temp\target"" action=""Update"" />
    </items>
    </ServerConfig>";

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ServerConfig));

ServerConfig config;

using(var stream = new StringReader(data))
using(var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
{
    config = (ServerConfig)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Load your document:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(fileManager.ConfigFile);
```

Then you will be able to select anything using XPath:

```
doc.SelectSingleNode(XPath); 
doc.SelectNodes(XPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `XmlNode`, I'd use `XmlElement`, as it has a nice method called `GetAttribute(string attributeName)` that's a little easier to work with than the `Attributes` indexer property on `XmlNode`. And, since `XmlElement`  derives from `XmlNode`, you  get added functionality while retaining the functionality of the base `XmlNode` class..

```
var items = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("items/item").Cast<XmlElement>().ToList();

// You can iterate over the list, here's how you'd get your attributes:
var Name = items[0].GetAttribute("name"); // Returns null if attribute doesn't exist, doesn't throw exception
var Source = items[0].GetAttribute("source");
var Destination = items[0].GetAttrubite("destination");
```

HTH.